# imaplib.py: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, github-actions, imaplib

I've set up a workflow on GitHub and when I run it, I'm getting the following error:

```
 1    Run python app.py
 2    python app.py
 3    shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
 4    env:
 5      pythonLocation: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.6/x64
 6      LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.6/x64/lib
 8  Traceback (most recent call last):
 9    File "/home/runner/work/Bot-Deschamps-Newsletter/Bot-Deschamps-Newsletter/app.py", line 9, in <module>
10      main()
11    File "/home/runner/work/Bot-Deschamps-Newsletter/Bot-Deschamps-Newsletter/app.py", line 5, in main
12      mail_connect()
13    File "/home/runner/work/Bot-Deschamps-Newsletter/Bot-Deschamps-Newsletter/read_email.py", line 13, in mail_connect
14      mailbox = MailBox(SMTP_SERVER).login(
15    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.6/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/imap_tools/mailbox.py", line 46, in login
16      login_result = self.box.login(username, password)
17    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.6/x64/lib/python3.9/imaplib.py", line 610, in login
18      typ, dat = self._simple_command('LOGIN', user, self._quote(password))
19    File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.6/x64/lib/python3.9/imaplib.py", line 1222, in _quote
20      arg = arg.replace('\\', '\\\\')
21  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
22  Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

This `imaplib.py` file isn't in my project, but I'm importing the `imap-tools` dependency and I don't know if it could be the cause.
Is it possible that this has something to do with it? The only solution would be to look for some other dependency or is there an alternative?

### EDIT 1:

Here is the file I run in the workflow:

```py
#app.py
from read_email import mail_connect

def main():
    mail_connect()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here in the workflow executed in GitHub Actions:

```yaml
#main.yml
name: Python Script Workflow

on:
  - cron: "*/10 11-13 * * 1-5"
  
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      name:
        required: true
        default: 'Tweet'
  
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository content
        uses: actions/checkout@v2 # Checkout the repository content to github runner.

      - name: Setup Python Version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.9.6

      - name: Install Python dependencies
        uses: py-actions/py-dependency-install@v2
        with:
          path: "requirements.txt"

      - name: Execute Python script # Run the app.py
        run: python app.py
```

And this is the `requirements.txt`:

```
imap-tools==0.49.1
python-dotenv==0.19.0
tweepy==4.0.1
```

### EDIT 2:

Here is the only file that uses `imap_toolts`:

```py
#read_email.py
from imap_tools import MailBox, MailMessageFlags, A
from os import getenv
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from post_tweet import post_tweet


def mail_connect():
    load_dotenv()
    FROM_EMAIL = getenv('FROM_EMAIL')
    FROM_PWD = getenv('FROM_PWD')
    SMTP_SERVER = "imap.gmail.com"

    mailbox = MailBox(SMTP_SERVER).login(
        FROM_EMAIL, FROM_PWD, initial_folder='INBOX')

    read_email(mailbox)


def read_email(mailbox):
    posts = []
    for msg in mailbox.fetch():
        posts = msg.text.replace('*', '').split('\r\n\r\n')
        posts = posts[2:-3]
        mark_as_read(mailbox)
        archive_message(mailbox, msg.uid)
    post_tweet(posts)


def mark_as_read(mailbox):
    flags = (MailMessageFlags.ANSWERED, MailMessageFlags.FLAGGED)
    mailbox.flag(mailbox.fetch(A(seen=False)), flags, True)
    mailbox.flag(mailbox.fetch("SENTON 01-Jan-2021"),
                 MailMessageFlags.SEEN, False)


def archive_message(mailbox, msg_uid):
    move_to = 'Tweeted'
    mailbox.move(msg_uid, move_to)
```

Comment: Seeing your code would help.

Comment: Most likely you're passing the None value into one of the functions from imap-tools that can't handle None values. Without seeing your python code, I can't offer any advice more specific than that.

Comment: I just edited my question including some files of project.

Comment: I suspect that when this runs as a github action, the environment variables you're getting email and password from aren't set in the environment where this is running, so the getenv calls are returning None.

Comment: I just updated the email and password environment variables, but the error remains.

Comment: Based on the stack trace and your code, at this line: `mailbox = MailBox(SMTP_SERVER).login(
        FROM_EMAIL, FROM_PWD, initial_folder='INBOX')` at least one of FROM_EMAIL or FROM_PWD is None. The only way I can see for that to happen is if getenv() is failing for one/both of these environment variables. How are you setting these in your github workflow environment?

Comment: In the [project](https://github.com/arnonrdp/Bot-Deschamps-Newsletter) I go to `Settings` > `Environments ` > `Production` > `Add Secret`. Now I'm suspecting it might have something to do with the variable. Shouldn't I declare in `main.yml` the environment where the variables are located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the environment variables for your email and password are not set in the GitHub workflow environment. Modify the YAML for your workflow as follows:

```yaml
environment:
  name: production

  - name: Execute Python script # Run the app.py
    env:
      FROM_PWD: ${{secrets.FROM_PWD}}
      FROM_EMAIL: ${{secrets.FROM_EMAIL}}

    run: python app.py
```

Modify if necessary based on how you named the secrets when you created them in GitHub.

Comment: The error went away, but during execution it returned `imaplib.error: LOGIN command error: BAD [b'Not enough arguments provided u9mb86962717qtx']`. I also tried using `env.FROM_PWD`, but this error persists.

Comment: I'm not familiar with GitHub Actions but is it normal for all these `steps` to be inside `build`? Or should they be in some `deployment` or `production`? [main.yml](https://github.com/arnonrdp/Bot-Deschamps-Newsletter/blob/main/.github/workflows/main.yml)

Comment: It was missing `environment:  name:  production`. After adding this and the other variables, everything now is working fine! I added it to your answer and accepted. I really appreciate your help! Thanks!!